# iOS: tvOS API availability error in iOS target | Swift Package

Tags: ios, swift, swift-package-manager

I have iOS application and i'm trying to add a package using swift package manager.
Compiler giving me error in a file in that package which is

> 'init(dynamicProvider:)' is only available in tvOS 13.0 or newer

i have double checked the Package.swift is only for iOS platform and there's also iOS 13.0 version check and fallback code is provided as well. But compiler is giving me error for tvOS. That's very strange.

[image]

Comment: What does your `Package.swift` file look like? More specifically do you have a `platforms` section? Also, what's run destination do you have selected?

Comment: @theoriginalbit platforms have iOS(.v9) only. Please explain destination?

Comment: In the top corner of Xcode, beside the run and stop buttons you have your Scheme, and to the right of Scheme is your run destination. Whatever destination is selected is what it will be trying to build your Swift Package against. So if it says "My Mac" then you will get errors about macOS versions, if "Apple TV" or some variant is selected you'll get the tvOS version errors. Make sure you have an iOS Simulator selected from the dropdown and the error should go away.

Comment: @theoriginalbit yes yes i was running the right scheme with right simulator. However restarting mac worked for me, i did tried cleaning project before but ended up on restarting mac. Lolzz

Comment: very strange. I typically find the wrong simulator is selected and changing it to the correct one, and sometimes performing a clean, will fix the problem.

Comment: the solution for me was to add tvOS support on my package platforms like such: `platforms: [
        .iOS(.v13),
        .macOS(.v10_15),
        .tvOS(.v13),
    ],`

Answer (score 0):

Restarting mac worked for me. I cleaned the project before, restarted xCode but eventually ended up on restarting mac. Lolzz very strange.